# How can I get a post by title in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

`Wordpress 3.0`

I want to have the contents of a specific post into a page by using the `title` of the post. As far as I can tell, I can't do it directly with `get_post()`.

I can assume what the brute force way might be, but I suspect there's a more elegant way?

Comment: if none of the answere you get here fit the bill, you might find http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ worth a go =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<!--1.Get post ID by post title if you know the title or the title variable-->
<?php
$posttitle = 'post_title';
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "'" );
echo $postid;
?>

<!--2.use get_post($post_id) to get whatever you want to echo-->
<?php
$getpost= get_post($postid);
$postcontent= $getpost->post_content;
echo $postcontent;
?>
```

Comment: Very bad practice to use an unescaped variable in the SQL like that.  If this data comes from the user, then it's dangerous because it allows an SQL injection attack.  Instead use $wpdb->prepare, as follows:  $postid = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = %s",$posttitle));

Answer (score 36):

```
get_page_by_title($id, OBJECT, 'post');
```

There ye go.

Comment: For future reference, `get_page_by_title()`'s second argument expects a string. However WP defines some top level variables such as OBJECT ('OBJECT'), ARRAY_N ('ARRAY_N'), and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

No need to SQL query's when you can use wordpress own functions for this.

```
$page = get_page_by_title( 'Startsida' );
$page_id = $page->ID;
```

Answer (score 4):

post_exists is a good function for that :

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_exists/

```
<?php

$post_id = post_exists('Your title');
// return id or 0 if post doesn't exists.

if($post_id>0)
    get_post($post_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376605/get-page-by-title-in-wordpress-how-to-use-to-fetch-posts/3377032#3377032) on a very similar question. Do **not** query the data base with an unescaped string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

1)

```
global $wpdb;
$your_title = "yourtitle";
$id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_name = $your_title");
echo $id;
```

or 2)

```
    $slug_to_get = 'my_title_or_slug';
    // you can use custom post type too
    $posttypee='post';

    $args=array(
      'title' => $slug_to_get,
      'post_type' => $posttypee,
      'post_status' => 'publish'
      );
    $my_posts = get_posts($args);
    if( $my_posts ) {
    echo 'ID on the first post found '.$my_posts[0]->ID;
    }
```

Comment: for security reasons should always use wp functions where possible. @see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12518634/288644