# Get WordPress post by post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code to show WordPress posts in an external website:

```
<?php
    require('wp_blog/wp-blog-header.php');
    
    if($_GET["p"] > '') { ?>
    
    <?php query_posts('p='.$_GET["p"].''); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&order=ASC&orderby=post_title');
    foreach ($posts as $post) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
        <?php the_date(); echo "<br />"; ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>    
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    <?php } ?>
```

Rather than selecting the post based on the ID, how can I make it select the post based on the post title?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get a post by title in Wordpress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591295/how-can-i-get-a-post-by-title-in-wordpress)

Comment: You need the page to show by slug?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use  `get_page_by_title()` to fetch post by title.Like this:

```
$page = get_page_by_title('About', OBJECT, 'post');
echo $page->ID
```

Details are [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title).

> OR custom query like this :

```
$posttitle = 'About';
$postid = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = '" . $posttitle . "'" );
echo $postid;
```

Comment: i tried doing: $page = get_page_by_title( 'Hello world!' );
 echo $page->ID but its not returning anything

Comment: pass second and third parameter with `hello world`.

Comment: what second and third parameter?

Comment: like this `get_page_by_title(('About', OBJECT, 'post');`

Comment: like this ? $page = get_page_by_title('Hello world!', OBJECT, 'post');

Comment: If I use this into the _main loop_, must I use `reset_query` or similar?

Comment: `get_page_by_title` can not render gutenberg blocks of the post or page.

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
$post_title = 'Contact';
$post_id = get_page_by_title($post_title, OBJECT, 'your_post_type_name');
echo $post_id->ID; // your id
```

Comment: get_page_by_title is deprecated. Try to use custom function

Answer (score 2):

Add Function Like this

```
function get_page_by_post_name($post_name, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'post' ){
    global $wpdb;
    $page = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", $post_name, $post_type ) );

    if ( $page ) return get_post( $page, $output );

    return null;
}

 add_action('init','get_page_by_post_name');
```

And run like that:

```
 $page = get_page_by_post_name('hello-world', OBJECT, 'post');
 echo $page->ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Function ***get_page_by_title()*** is deprecated. This is another simple function for this issue:

```
function get_post_id_by_title( $title, $post_type ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts where post_type='".$post_type."' AND post_title='".$title."'");
}
```